# Multiple cases that allows different conversion of column that is being checked in WHERE CASE WHEN clause

Tags: t-sql, where-clause

```
SELECT Clmn
FROM Tbl T
INNER JOIN SomeotherTbl
WHERE CONVERT(varchar(10), T.[Date], 120) = 
CASE @SortOrder 
    WHEN '1' THEN CONVERT(varchar(10), GETDATE(), 120)
    WHEN '2' THEN CONVERT(varchar(7),  GETDATE(), 120)
    WHEN '3' THEN CONVERT(varchar(4),  GETDATE(), 120)
END
```

So i have a Date column that i converted to varchar , but i would like to convert it to different length according to @SortOrder , what's the best solution ?

Comment: `WHERE CASE in a WHERE CASE` - what??

Comment: It's generally better to use AND/OR constructions instead of case expressions in WHERE clauses.

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. That query is product specific in several ways.

Comment: @jarlh its TSQL yea i didn't think of that i'm gonna try it out tnx

Comment: @jarlh but i need to ask if input parameter is 1or2or3 then do the where clause idk if it's possible

Comment: I don't understand why you would compare a varchar(10) to a varchar(7) or varchar(4) in your `WHERE` statement. Those will never return true, right?

Comment: @Fraukje yea that's the problem i need to swap in what D.[Date] converts to (varchar 10 or varchar 7 or varchar 4 ) in order to be able to compare it to CASE varchars

Comment: Can you maybe give a small example of your data and your desired outcome? I'm a bit confused what you want to do

Comment: @Fraukje here is the data http://prntscr.com/iiced8 and what i need to do is get Top10Products for  last day/month/year , and the column i'm checking is Date from Document , and this is the result of successful top10products by day http://prntscr.com/iicf3h

Comment: @Fraukje results came back because i locked this Document.Date to yyyy/mm/dd with this CONVERT(varchar(10),D.[Date],120) , but i need others to depending on input parameter hope it helped you help me .. :P

Comment: This makes no sense to me.  It is nice to show what you tried but here I think you describe what you need.

Comment: @Paparazzi Yep , I'm senseless a lot when it comes to sql sorry , tnx for trying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Like` instead of `=`:

```
WHERE CONVERT(varchar(10),D.[Date],120) LIKE 
CASE @SortOrder 
    WHEN '1' THEN CONVERT(varchar(10),GETDATE(),120)
    WHEN '2' THEN CONVERT(varchar(7),GETDATE(),120) +'%'
    WHEN '3' THEN CONVERT(varchar(4),GETDATE(),120) +'%'
END
```

Another option (without using case) is this:

```
WHERE (@SortOrder > '3' OR YEAR(D.[Date]) = YEAR(GETDATE()))
AND   (@SortOrder > '2' OR MONTH(D.[Date]) = MONTH(GETDATE()))
AND   (@SortOrder > '1' OR DAY(D.[Date]) = DAY(GETDATE()))
```

And yet another option, that will work for versions 2012 or higher, and is a little more complicated, but if you have an index on the `[Date]` column will allow SQL Server to use it:

```
DECLARE @Date date = GETDATE()
DECLARE @ThisMonth date = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@Date), MONTH(@Date), 1)
DECLARE @ThisYear date = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@Date), 1, 1)

SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE 
    (@SortOrder = '1' AND D.[Date] = @Date)
OR  (@SortOrder = '2' AND D.[Date] >=  @ThisMonth AND D.[Date] < DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @ThisMonth))
OR  (@SortOrder = '3' AND D.[Date] >= @ThisYear AND D.[Date] < DATEADD(YEAR, 1, @ThisYear))
```

[You can see a live demo on rextester.](http://rextester.com/RMBQM47575)

Comment: i was trying to use IS LIKE haha , but still like doesn't work probably because of the length of varchars idk

Comment: i forgot to add % mby it'll work let me try it ,SORRY

Comment: @АлексаЈевтић Glad to help :-). BTW, I've updated my answer and the live demo with one more option. If you have a large table with an index on the Date column and your version of sql server is 2012 or higher, I would say it's the best option.

Comment: Nice i didn't know DATEFROMPARTS exists , i like it and will probably use it one day , thanks ! But i will stick to first solution it looks kinda nicer idk :P

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare year, month, and day there are better ways

```
select CONVERT(varchar(10), GETDATE(), 120), CONVERT(varchar(7), GETDATE(), 120), CONVERT(varchar(4), GETDATE(), 120)  
      , DATEPART(year, getdate()), DATEPART(month, getdate()),  DATEPART(day, getdate())
```

> 2018-02-22    2018-02 2018    2018    2   22

Comment: at first i was working with datepart but then i realized i'm getting only mm and i need yyyy/mm so i decided to work with varchar conversion , but thanks anyway